# org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONObject

Tags: java, json, sqlite

I keep getting this error and already searched a lot and cant seem to solve it. Basically i am trying to read a json file and store some of its data in a database. Hope you guys know how to solve this!
This json file is from a statistics site and i want to store the most important data in a database table i created with SQLite.
Thanks for all the help, cheers :D

This is the error i keep getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to class org.json.simple.JSONObject (org.json.simple.JSONArray and org.json.simple.JSONObject are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.arrowplus.arrowplus.Connect.connect(Connect.java:49)
    at com.arrowplus.arrowplus.Connect.main(Connect.java:86)
```

This is my JSON file:

```
[ {
  "IndicadorCod" : "0010042",
  "IndicadorDsg" : "Valor mediano de avaliação bancária (€/ m²) por Localização geográfica (Município - 2013) e Tipo de construção; Mensal - INE, Inquérito à avaliação bancária na habitação",
  "MetaInfUrl" : "https://www.ine.pt/bddXplorer/htdocs/minfo.jsp?var_cd=0010042&lingua=PT",
  "DataExtracao" : "2020-06-29T15:55:51.640+01:00",
  "DataUltimoAtualizacao" : "2020-06-29",
  "UltimoPref" : "Maio de 2020",
  "Dados" : {
    "202005" : [ {
      "geocod" : "1701106",
      "geodsg" : "Lisboa",
      "dim_3" : "T",
      "dim_3_t" : "Total",
      "valor" : "3084"
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

And this is my code:

```
package com.arrowplus.arrowplus;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;


public class Connect {


    public static Connection ConnectToDB() throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;

            // db parameters
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlite/AP.db";
            // create a connection to the database
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

            System.out.println("Connection to SQLite has been established.");
            return conn;

    }

    public static void connect() {


            //Creating a JSONParser object
            JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

            try {

                //Parsing the contents of the JSON file
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/arrowplus/Desktop/jsonTest.json"));
                //Retrieving the array
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("");

                Connection con = ConnectToDB();
                PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ine_data values (id, date, valor, DataUltimoAtualizacao, geodsg)");
                for (Object object : jsonArray) {
                    JSONObject record = (JSONObject) object;
                    int id = Integer.parseInt((String) record.get("id"));
                    String date = (String) record.get("date");
                    int valor = Integer.parseInt((String) record.get("valor"));
                    String dateUpdate = (String) record.get("DataUltimoAtualizacao");
                    long dateUpdate2 = Date.valueOf(dateUpdate).getTime();
                    String city = (String) record.get("geodsg");
                    pstmt.setInt(1, id);
                    pstmt.setString(2, date);
                    pstmt.setInt(3, valor);
                    pstmt.setDate(4, new Date(dateUpdate2));
                    pstmt.setString(5, city);
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                }
                System.out.println("Records inserted.....");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main (String[]args){
            connect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You trying to cast a json from JSONObject to JSONArray which is incorrect. Instead parse it to a JSONArray directly as your input file has a json array and not object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read file into `String` and parse as `JSONArray`:

```
// Read file into a string
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    stringBuilder.append(line);
    stringBuilder.append(ls);
}
// delete the last new line separator
stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length() - 1);
reader.close();
```

Convert the `String` to a `JSONArray`:

```
String content = stringBuilder.toString();
// convert to json array
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(content);
```

Read values one by one:

```
JSONObject firstJsonObject = json.getJSONObject(1);
```

or iterate through the `JSONArray`

```
for (int i = 0; i < json.length; i++){
  JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(i);
  // do something
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: thanks man! but i dont seem to find a way to insert values into my table after this.
can you give me an example with one of my values inserting it into the table?
also, where should i insert all this code you gave me? im kind of lost here, im also new to this..

Comment: My answer should fix your exception. You can add this code to read the file (the place you have commented `Parsing the contents of the JSON file`). Once read, you can iterate and populate your query. The way you have written your prepared statement is wrong. Refer: https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface

Comment: i get an error when trying to convert String to a JSONArray with the "content" string: Expected 0 arguments but found 1

Comment: probably your file is not in proper json format or something, try printing the string and see whats the value

Comment: the string prints exatcly my json file, and it is on .json format

Comment: the error is in this line: JSONArray json = new JSONArray(content);

Comment: make sure u are using `org.JSONArray` and not something else

Comment: i am using org.json.simple.JSONArray, the one you said doesnt let me use a for each cycle..

Comment: What does each cycle mean and `org.json` is better, try to move !

Comment: "for: each" cycle. My program has errors if i use org.json, so i dont know what to do

Comment: `org.JSONArray` doesnt work with `foreach`, use legacy loops `for (int i = 0; i < json.length; i++)`

Answer (score -1):

Test with something like this instead.

```
Object object = (Object) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/arrowplus/Desktop/jsonTest.json"));
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(object);
```

Comment: There you are trying to cast JSONObject to JSONArray:                 
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("");

Comment: doing that, will i have to change my for loop after that? to insert values into my table?